# Access local module.exports with Dart and JS interop

Tags: javascript, node.js, dart, commonjs, dart-js-interop

My goal is to reuse the code from Dart project in JavaScript as a library and either import it directly in Node.js or bundle for client-side JS as CommonJS.

Currently Dart2JS forces the use of globals, particularly `self` which is unavailable in Node.

Data is exported from `main`:

```
@JS('module.exports')
//external NodeModuleExports get nodeModuleExports;
external dynamic get nodeModuleExports;

main() {
  nodeModuleExports.foo = 'foo';
}
```

This won't work at least because `module` is treated as global instead of local variable, `nodeModuleExports.foo` is compiled to `self.module.exports.foo` and not `module.exports.foo`.

I assume that [node_preamble](https://github.com/mbullington/node_preamble.dart) is supposed to address this but not sure how it can be applied to this case.

How can new properties be added to `module.exports` JavaScript local in Dart?

Answer (score 1):

You're correct about using [node_preamble](https://pub.dev/packages/node_preamble). When Dart2JS builds your code, it will always append your `module.exports.foo` with `self.module.exports.foo`. As you said this prevents the function from being exported.

Now, the purpose of a preamble is to overwrite `self.exports` with simply `exports` to get the desired behavior. You can see this in [node_preamble](https://pub.dev/packages/node_preamble) here:

[image of node_preamble code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QqBCP.png)

(node_preamble does a few more things but they aren't relevant in this post)

To get to the solution, you can **append** the code in [node_preamble](https://github.com/mbullington/node_preamble.dart/blob/master/lib/preamble.js), or (in your case), just add `self.exports = exports;` to the top of your generated .js file. In my case, we added a bash script that automatically appended our custom preamble after our code is generated.

[image of final code that has fixed exports](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wfsuW.png)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it sheds some light. Please, provide the code instead of images, this will improve the post.